# How can I HIDE SSRS subreports and drill through reports in the SSRS browser

Tags: reporting-services

I am working in Visual Studio 2015 and when I deploy an SSRS drill through report or subreport I have to deploy both the main report and these reports respectfully from my local box to the REPORTING SERVER. The problem is that both reports are displayed in the browser when a user accesses the reporting server via their browser.  Is there a way to HIDE the drill through or subreport from the browser so that a user cannot see it in the browser but it still executes from the main report? 
Any help/direction would be appreciated.  In the PIC below I need to HIDE the Cycle Time By Adjuster Detail report in the browser so that the user does not choose it.

[image]

Comment: FYI: The list view you show above always shows hidden items, the default Tile view does not show hidden items by default.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Hide This Item checkbox to hide the report.

[image]

This will hide the selected report from the regular view. The user could still find it, though, by going to the settings and checking the Show Hidden Items box.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately, the item is grayed-out but still visible and the user can still click on it and get the error that there is no parameter. Any other suggestions?  Thanks

Comment: The other way that I have done is to put the reports into a subfolder and hide the subfolder. Or you could put them in another folder altogether on the main page with Data Sources and Datasets. At least it won't be as prevalent as when it's in your report folder.

Answer (score 0):

Each report in your report server should have Security settings that can be adjusted per user.  I believe I'm using an older version of report server, but the concept is the same.  You simply need to adjust the permissions of the user you don't want to see the reports.

Right-clicking the report should look a little something like this:

[image: img1]

This version has a `Security` option, yours may just say `Manage` and you'll have to navigate to the security tab.  I haven't personally tested this, but you should be able to remove the `Browser` permission from the specified user to hide the report in the report server.

Comment: Hi Steve, unfortunately, this didn't work but thanks for trying.